# Preserve history of moved TFS folders in git-tfs

Tags: git, tfs, migration, git-tfs

I am going to migrate my project (folder) from TFS to git using git-tfs. The problem is that the folder once was moved in TFS from one place to another. TFS history for the folder shows all changesets from the beginning, but `git-tfs clone` clones only the changesets, which happened after the move.

Is it possible to clone the old change sets too? Preferably together with the new changesets, but at least maybe to another git repo?

Upd. I've tried some ideas but they all failed:

1. One could clone from the old folder location. But there is no that location in the current change set.
2. One could clone from the last change set when older location was present. But `git tfs clone` has no option to use specific changeset, only `quick-clone` has.
3. One could `quick-clone` the first changeset at the old location (it works) and then `fetch` the changes. But `fetch` fails with error "No appropriate mapping exists for ...". I've tried adding old and new tfs remotes to the same repo, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [work in progress](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/480) already working quite well that support this case.

Just compile it yourself and give it a try!

Comment: Tried the current state of the rename_branch, but the resul was completely screwed up. Posted a comment to the pull request with the details.

Comment: The discussion on GitHub somehow ended with no result. Could you estimate the chances it will be handled or tell me what should be done?

Comment: If I understand well your problem, it's another horrible case that TFS permit. It will be hard to managed it because TFS give us bad branch hierarchy that prevent us to detect it :( I see 2 solutions... In the long term, let the user specify it's own branch hierarchy in file and accept this file in input and ignore data tfs give us. In the short term, you must modify the source code to manage your case with describing your hierarchy inside the git-tfs source code (someone already did that) too override data get from tfs...

Comment: Thank you. I suddenly tried git-tf, and it worked. I don't know what did they do to manage this case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried `git-tf` instead of `git-tfs` and it suddenly worked, so the migration problem was solved.